# Bootstrap background-cover set image within "container-fluid" so height fills page

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Aloha,

Here is my pen -- http://codepen.io/DarrenHaynes/full/gLoYpp/

And the code from that pen:

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid spiritual-background">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
      <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h2>When the going gets tough - the tough get going<br>There's no knowing how far they are going.<br>What if I add another line.</h2>
      <h3>- Billy Ocean</h3>
    </div>
      <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  </div>
   <div class="toolbar">
      <button type="button" id="spiritualQuote" class="btn btn-info"> Spiritual Quotes</button>
      <button type="button" id="techQuote" class="btn btn-info"> Tech Quotes</button>
      <button type="button" id="lifeQuote" class="btn btn-info"> Life Quotes</button>
      <button type="button" id="inspirationalQuote" class="btn btn-info"> Inspirational Quotes</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.spiritual-background {
  background: url(https://s19.postimg.org/tx1z2cgcz/feng_sway_rocks.jpg);
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}

.toolbar {
  margin-bottom: 4%;
  margin-left: 56%;
}

.row {
  margin-top: 8%;
  margin-bottom: 7%;
}
h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

h3 {
  text-align: right;
}
```

I am trying to figure out how to get the background image's height to be fully shown, while it still covers the page. As it stands the rocks in the image are cut off at the bottom of the image, but I want to see the whole height of the image.

I want to avoid putting the image into "html" or "body" tags - I will be using jquery to remove and add classes within the "container-fluid" tag to change the background image when pressing one of the 4 buttons in the toolbar. In other words ".spiritual-background" will be removed and placed with another class I am yet to create.

Comment: You have 2 options. 1) Use `background-size: cover` and the browser will make the image full-screen, but will cut off portions of the background to adapt to the aspect ratio of the browser. Or 2) stretch the image so it's 100% width and 100% height and match whatever the aspect ratio of the browser viewport is, but that will skew the image unless the browser aspect ratio matches the image aspect ratio exactly. Which do you prefer?

Comment: Let's go with image stretching. I can crop it later also if the stretching takes things to far off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers everyone. With a little more research I found something on codepen that gave the exact result I needed - https://codepen.io/theiwaz/pen/vybjc

here is the css from that pen:

```
html, body{
  height: 100%;
}
body { 
            background-image: url(http://ppcdn.500px.org/75319705/1991f76c0c6a91ae1d23eb94ac5c7a9f7e79c480/2048.jpg) ;
            background-position: center center;
            background-repeat:  no-repeat;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-size:  cover;
            background-color: #999;

}
```

Setting the parent elements of html to 100% height and the body tag also to maintain at static screen height. I modified this slightly by adding a percentage position to the `background-position` height parameter to get the image to my preference.

Answer (score 2):

To make the area full-screen, just put it at the root of the page, make it absolutely positioned with `0` for all the position coordinates, and give it a negative z-index so it doesn't sit on top of any other elements.

Re: the background image and how it adapts to the page fullscreen-wise, you have 2 options.

`background-size: cover` (what you have now) and the browser will make the image full-screen, but will cut off portions of the background to adapt to the aspect ratio of the browser.

```css
.spiritual-background {
  background: url(https://s19.postimg.org/tx1z2cgcz/feng_sway_rocks.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.toolbar {
  margin-bottom: 4%;
  margin-left: 56%;
}

.row {
  margin-top: 8%;
  margin-bottom: 7%;
}
h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

h3 {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid spiritual-background">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
      <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h2>When the going gets tough - the tough get going<br>There's no knowing how far they are going.<br>What if I add another line.</h2>
      <h3>- Billy Ocean</h3>
    </div>
      <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  </div>
   <div class="toolbar">
      <button type="button" id="spiritualQuote" class="btn btn-info"> Spiritual Quotes</button>
      <button type="button" id="techQuote" class="btn btn-info"> Tech Quotes</button>
      <button type="button" id="lifeQuote" class="btn btn-info"> Life Quotes</button>
      <button type="button" id="inspirationalQuote" class="btn btn-info"> Inspirational Quotes</button>
    </div>
</div>
CSS:
```

`background-size: 100% 100%;` will show the entire image, and will stretch the height and width of the image to match whatever the size of the element it's applied to. This will skew the image in 99% of cases, unless the browser/element is exactly the same aspect ratio of the image.

```css
    .spiritual-background {
      background: url(https://s19.postimg.org/tx1z2cgcz/feng_sway_rocks.jpg);
      background-size: 100% 100%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
      z-index: -1;
    }

    .toolbar {
      margin-bottom: 4%;
      margin-left: 56%;
    }

    .row {
      margin-top: 8%;
      margin-bottom: 7%;
    }
    h2 {
      text-align: center;
    }

    h3 {
      text-align: right;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container-fluid spiritual-background">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6"></div>
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        </div>
          <div class="col-md-1"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-7"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h2>When the going gets tough - the tough get going<br>There's no knowing how far they are going.<br>What if I add another line.</h2>
          <h3>- Billy Ocean</h3>
        </div>
          <div class="col-md-1"></div>
      </div>
       <div class="toolbar">
          <button type="button" id="spiritualQuote" class="btn btn-info"> Spiritual Quotes</button>
          <button type="button" id="techQuote" class="btn btn-info"> Tech Quotes</button>
          <button type="button" id="lifeQuote" class="btn btn-info"> Life Quotes</button>
          <button type="button" id="inspirationalQuote" class="btn btn-info"> Inspirational Quotes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

[image][image]

Hi

They are not all your codes.

The problem is also in the other ones.

1- Remove background url from class ".spiritual-background".

2- Add these properties to class".fullpage":

```
background: url(https://s19.postimg.org/tx1z2cgcz/feng_sway_rocks.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
```

3- if you remove "iframe" inside the div with the id = "result-iframe-wrap" you  will be able to see the background image.by using background-position you can move the image to the right and left / top and bottom to display every part of the image you aim.

background-position : 40% 30%;

Iframe it self has another html tag and the body which is coming on the top of the body of your main page which is not a correct way to do.

4-If you add below codes to the body with the class of fullpage you can find the text and the buttons but you need to do the styles from beginning:

```
<div class="container-fluid spiritual-background">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
      <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h2>When the going gets tough - the tough get going<br>There's no knowing how far they are going.<br>What if I add another line.</h2>
      <h3>- Billy Ocean</h3>
    </div>
      <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  </div>
   <div class="toolbar">
      <button type="button" id="spiritualQuote" class="btn btn-info"> Spiritual Quotes</button>
      <button type="button" id="techQuote" class="btn btn-info"> Tech Quotes</button>
      <button type="button" id="lifeQuote" class="btn btn-info"> Life Quotes</button>
      <button type="button" id="inspirationalQuote" class="btn btn-info"> Inspirational Quotes</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

*If you send all the other codes I will be able to help you more in    fixing all.

Comment: Hi Negin. Thanks for the help. That is all the code, I created it with codepen where "HTML" and "body" tags are not shown but are there. If you go to the codepen link you will see the HTML and CSS.